# Create a file on specific node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Do you know if it's possible with Kubernetes cli to create a file on a specific node ?

i mean you are working since the master and you want to create a file on node2 only .

Comment: What you mean by "file"? Do you mean Pod?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Pod on specific node by specifying `nodeName` in it's manifest, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
  nodeName: kube-01
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the `master node` which naturally has network connectivity with `worker nodes` why don't you simply use [`scp` command](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) ?

But answering your specific question: **No, you can not create a file on a worker node simply by using `kubectl` command**.

You can create a `Pod` based on specific `yaml` manifest which will be scheduled on a specific `node` and **will create such file on that node for you**. It can be scheduled on a specific `node` automatically, based on node affinity rule, defined in a [local](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) `PersistentVolume` (btw. this is one of its advantage over `hostpath`), which will be used for sharing data between your `Pod` and `node`. So basically your `Pod` can write directly to a specific path on a specific node, on which it will be automatically scheduled, based on `nodeAffinity` defined in local `PV`.